# express res.send http code and text catch up by backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, express

i try to programming a register with express and backbone.js. the express part looks like that

```
    app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {

    var name = req.param("name", null);
    var country = req.param("country", null);
    var email = req.param("email", null);
    var cemail = req.param("cemail", null);
    var password = req.param("password", null);

    if (email !== cemail ||
    !validate.Email(email) ||
    email == null) {
        console.log("There is something wrong with email address");
        res.send(400, "Please check your email address.");
        return;
    };

    if (password == null || !validate.Password(password)) {
        console.log("There is something wrong with password");
        res.send(400, "Password doesn't match security requirements");
        return;
    };

    if (name == null || country == null) {
        console.log("Some fields is not filled with value.");
        res.send(400);
        return;
    };

    signup(name, country, email, password);
    res.send(200);

});
```

if an user give invalid email address, then it gonna respond with http code 400 and some text. Now my question is, how can i catch up this text, on the backbone.js site. it is possible or not. Frontend backbone.js code

```
   $.post('/signup', {
        name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
        country: $('input[name=country]').val(),
        email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
        cemail: $('input[name=cemail]').val(),
        password: $('input[name=password]').val()
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(){
        console.log("Sign up error");
    });
    return false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `$.post` `error` callback will be passed the `response` object and that will contain the text error message.

```
.error(function(response){
    console.log("Sign up error", response.responseText);
});
```

Comment: first so much for help, but how do you know that, i was look at jquery documentation but didn't find anything from response object.